# How can I call the first image in a folder to display in my img tag?

Tags: html

I want to be able to call the first image from a folder. The reason behind this is that the file name will always be changing as the user will be able to put whatever image they want inside of the template.

Comment: You can probably put the names of the files in the folder in an array and unshift() the first name from it.

Comment: You won't be able to do this just with HTML. What else are you using? JavaScript? PHP? Python? etc...

Answer (score 1):

**Using PHP:**

**Step 1**

use `glob()` function to search for all the pathnames matching pattern for image extensions `{jpg,png,gif}` inside your directory path using `GLOB_BRACE`

**Step 2**

Confirm atleast one image is found

**Step 3**

Use `img` tag to display the image

```
<?php
$images = glob("path/to/your/folder/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
if(isset($images[0]) && file_exists($images[0])){
    echo '<img src="'.$images[0].'"/>';
}
?>
```